# Amazon alexa skill kit with php mysql

Tags: javascript, database, alexa-skills-kit

There's a database that already exists which contains details about health information like tablet name,
Just like how alexa uses the LIST_OF_ITEMS in minecraft helper, I want my skill to access my MySQL database and get the results and speak it out,
The documentation given is only for dynamoDB, and Account linking doesn't provide help to accessing existing database, Can you please help?
Thanks